# Multiple destinations found with a deep link

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I am using navigation components nd  I have a deep link in my nav graph while trying to build the app i am getting messages "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors " and in Merged Manifest section i am getting the error as "Multiple destinations found with a deep link"

I tried invalidating cache and Restarting but still the build failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Check deep link URI it should not contain an underscore

2)Check deep link id, two deep links ids should not be the same

Comment: thanks man underscore in deep link url was causing the issue